# R how to make lm() to reappear the curve formula

Tags: r, tidyverse, lm

I use formula `y=x^3+3` to generate data.frame `df` with variables x and y,
but when i using `lm()` to describe the relation of xy, i get `y=81450x-5463207.2`. This is really different with the original `y=x^3+3`.
How to make lm() or using other way to  reappear the original formula ?

```
library(tidyverse)
mf <- function(x){
  y=x^3+3
}

df=data.frame()
for (i in 1:300){
  df[i,1]=i
  df[i,2]=mf(i)
}
names(df) <- c('x','y')


model <- lm(y~x,data = df)
model$coefficients
```

Comment: You have to specify the cubic relation, i.e. `model <- lm(y ~ I(x^3), data = df)`, and the model will tell you both the coefficients are 3 and 1.

Comment: Thanks, I(x^3) can reappear the original formula,  but if I don't know the original formula ,how I know should input  I(x^3)  ? (I just want to describe given  trend )

Comment: Interestingly enough `model <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 5),data = df); round(model$coefficients, 2)` will not find the right solution???

Comment: @Bernhard, that's because you specified the polynomial using a different basis.  Use `model <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 5, raw=TRUE),data = df)` instead.

Comment: @user2554330 Note to my future self:  RTFM!  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*@DarrenTsai ansered first in the comments, if he also writes an answer, consider to accept his' first.*

`lm(y ~ x, data = df)` searches for a solution in the form of y = b0 + b1*x which is not how the data were generated. You can tell `lm` to include `x^n` using `I()` as in

```
lm(y ~ x + I(x^2), + I(x^3) + I(x^4))
```

a short form for `x + I(x^2), + I(x^3) + ... + I(x^n)` is `poly(x, n)' as used in the comment of user2554330

Let me do some changes of your code for better coding style

```r
# library(tidyverse)  -- you did not use any of this so there is no need to load it
mf <- function(x){ #  -- writing this in one without curly braces is an option 
  y=x^3+3          #  -- this will be retrieved as Intercept 3 plus 1*x^3
}


#for (i in 1:300){ -- there is really no need for a loop here
#  df[i,1]=i
#  df[i,2]=mf(i)
#}
#names(df) <- c('x','y')

df <- data.frame(x = 1:300,   #-- this is shorter and faster then the loop
                 y = mf(1:300))

model <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 5, raw = TRUE), data = df)
round(coef(model), 4)
#>             (Intercept) poly(x, 5, raw = TRUE)1 
#>                       3                       0 
#> poly(x, 5, raw = TRUE)2 poly(x, 5, raw = TRUE)3 
#>                       0                       1 
#> poly(x, 5, raw = TRUE)4 poly(x, 5, raw = TRUE)5 
#>                       0                       0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

`(Intercept)` is three and the `I(x^3)` coded here as `poly(df$x, 5, raw = TRUE)3` is one as coded in `mf`.